# Add parameter from URL to an element and scroll to element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a url like the following on a button:

```
www.mywebsite.com/infopage?scrollTo=section-header&#tab3
```

When I click the button, it goes to the above URL as expected and opens the tab named `tab3` which is set as the anchor.

However, I want it to land on a particular heading within the content of `tab3`.

Can this be done with vanilla JavaScript.? I'm trying to add the 'section-header' value from the URL as a second anchor and scroll to it somehow.

Is `window.scrollTo` an option here?

Thanks in advance for any help, I've searched around for how I might do this and am a beginner with JavaScript.

Comment: _“I'm trying to add the 'section-header' value from the URL as a second anchor”_ - are you referring to the fragment/hash portion here, the part after `#`? You can not have a “second anchor” in the URL.

Comment: Got ya, so I cannot use a second anchor that helps me rule out that option, thanks Cbroe. tab3 opens as expected but I need to scroll to a heading within the tab and not just have the page go to the tab3 anchor.

Comment: Why not just have the given header as the anchor?

Comment: You can perhaps combine two values into a single hash, but then you would have to re-implement the part that automatically opens the correct tab.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scrollIntoView` you can get a similar scrolling effect to anchors:

```js
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var scrollTo = url.searchParams.get("scrollTo");
document.getElementById(scrollTo).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Note: `url.searchParams` has [limited support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) (no IE support). If you need to support older browsers, you can either use [this polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params) or some other way to get the parameter from the URL.